# Swift Charts: Draw A Line Chart Where Line Color is Determined by the Y-Value

Tags: ios, swiftui, charts

I am trying to use Swift Charts to draw the below graph.  I am having trouble figuring out how to change the color of the line based on it's Y value.  In the graph below, different ranges of Y have different colors assigned to them and the line reflects that.

[Desired Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRuNY.png)

I tried to set the line color using the foreground of the LineMark, but it seems to only take the first color assignment and ignore any others set on it.

```
Chart {
    ForEach(plotItemSeries) { plotItem in
        LineMark(x: .value("XVAL", plotItem.xVal),
                 y: .value("YVAL", plotItem.yVal))
        .foregroundStyle(plotItem.zoneColor) // <== color assigned base on y-val
    }
}
```

[Attempt #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXiFg.png)

I tried using a foreground scale but it just broke it up into multiple series like you would expect.

```
Chart {
    ForEach(plotItemSeries) { plotItem in
        LineMark(x: .value("XVAL", plotItem.xVal),
                 y: .value("YVAL", plotItem.yVal))
        .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Zone", plotItem.zoneColorName)) // <== "gray", "blue", etc..
    }
}
.chartForegroundStyleScale(["gray": Color("grayCustom"),
                            "green": Color("greenCustom"),
                            "blue": Color("blueCustom"),
                            "orange": Color("orangeCustom"),
                            "red": Color("redCustom")])
```

[Attempt #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXbzV.png)

Any ideas how to set the color of the line depending on it's y value?

Comment: Can you provide your full data and code, what you are trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out `.linearGradient(_ gradient: Gradient, startPoint: UnitPoint, endPoint: UnitPoint) -> LinearGradient` is the correct approach for this.
The Gradient.Stops are mapped to a UnitPoint which maps to the bounding box of the line drawn so the color boundary y-vals have to be converted to the unit point value which maps to the y-val of the color boundary.

For a simple example, if we want to draw the line blue below y-val of 5 and green above, and the line is: (0,0) to (10,10) then the unit point value that corresponds to the transition point is 0.5.

To get a crisp color transition we just define the gradient so that the portion where the color changes is too small to render:

```
let stops = [
  Gradient.Stop(color: .red, location: 0.0),
  Gradient.Stop(color: .red, location: 0.5),
  Gradient.Stop(color: .green, location: 0.50001),
  Gradient.Stop(color: .green, location: 1.0)
]
```

Thus the correct approach looks something like:

```
Chart {
  ForEach(plotItemSeries) { plotItem in
      LineMark(x: .value("XVAL", plotItem.xVal),
               y: .value("YVAL", plotItem.yVal))
      .foregroundStyle(.linearGradient(Gradient(stops: stops),
                                       startPoint: .bottom,
                                       endPoint: .top))
  }
}
```

The resulting graph line (using the original data) looks close to the original graph we were trying to match:  [Graph With SwiftCharts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgsi3.png)

Comment: How would you use this though so that the Gradient didn't always start and end with your data set's min and max?  In other words if I have a heart rate chart with heart rates from say 70 to 150bpm, but I want the gradient to indicate heart rate zones, so say zone 5 is purple and begins at 170bpm, my data set of 70-150 would only show colors below purple? 

Comment: @GarySabo Note this question was about coloring the plotted line.  So, if the data never reaches the purple zone (e.g. largest heart rate is 150, but purple zone minimum is 170) the plotted line shouldn't be colored purple at any point.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, it might what you are trying to achieve.

```
Chart {
    ForEach(plotItemSeries) { plotItem in
        LineMark(x: .value("XVAL", plotItem.xVal),
                 y: .value("YVAL", plotItem.yVal))
        .foregroundStyle(
                .linearGradient(
                // You can have more colours here depends on your data.
                colors: [.blue, .red],
                startPoint: .bottom,
                endPoint: .top)
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: this answer is almost correct.  However, the color transitions need to be crisp and line up with specific y-values which this does not.  However, it turns out `.linearGradient` is the way to go once these concerns are addressed.